# One custom display form for all the lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Good day to you. I am newbie in SharePoint 2013 so please bear with me. I have created around 15 lists in my website each containing same columns but different data (they differ semantically).

I am aware that we can change the default view, edit and display form for each list by creating new form in SharePoint Designer 2013. This seems like a very bad approach as far as the maintenance is concerned. I know my lists are exactly the same so why do I have to create same 15 display forms for each of the lists?

Is there a way to create one custom Display form (may be in a central location, i don't know i am just thinking :P ) for all the lists? Is there a way to tell a list to use a specific display form? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to write the solution which I implemented as it might help others as well. (Thanks Hiren and Mihir for your valuable inputs)

I had 15 lists and I was showing the data to the user using content search web part with custom display template. All of the lists were using the same display template so I made a new page just to show the item details. In the display template I pointed the item URL (i hijacked the list name and the current item id) to my new page and displayed the item. Let me know if anyone is interested in the whole solution or further elaboration is required.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you have 15 lists with same set of columns. You want to change the display/look of the form. All 15 lists should have same look and feel right!! If yes, then why don't you try with some html, javascript solution. Since you are in sharepoint 2013, javascript support for solutions is very good like rest queries. You can use [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) also. 
If you want to to add data to the list whenever you click on the "New Item" link in the list then hijack this link such that it should navigate to your custom form. Pass your list name as query parameter. Whenever user is saving the form, get the list name from the query parameter and save the data to that list.
There could be another ways also to achieve the solution with html and javascript.

Useful links:
[Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx), [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx), [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yes u understood correctly. Can u provide an example for html, javascript solution?

Comment: Updated with links. Please find it

Answer (score 0):

Sam I think you can create a custom content type and create custom display form for your content type. Enable the content type in each of your lists so automatically this customized form would be available.

The advantage of this approach is that suppose if you need one more list after some time you can just add this content type and your form would be available into the new list as well.

The approach is explained in the link below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2009/06/06/define-custom-new-edit-display-forms-for-content-types.aspx

Check this one also
https://joshmccarty.com/2011/02/sharepoint-custom-list-with-custom-content-types-and-custom-display-forms/

Comment: Hiren, thanks for the great input. I have implemented this solution but the problem is I am not getting any results.

I created a content type and assigned it to my two lists. Now when I click on the individual list item to view it, the browser takes me to custom display page but doesn't display any result in fact doesn't display anything at all other than the navigation. Could this be due to the fact that for testing purposes I copied the default display form from another existing list and assigned it to the content type?

Comment: Yes it is important that you implement the form correctly. If you just copy paste the code which might or might not be compatible with your content type then it could be the issue. I would say instead of copy pasting code from another list just try to modify the forms created by the designer for your content type it would be much more easier and bug free.